# Why do the Vikings warriors train with real weapons?

Tags: realism, historical-accuracy, vikings

In the Vikings TV show we often see warriors training with each others using real weapons. This can be seen both for vikings' and other kingdoms' warriors.

As far I know warriors used to train with wooden swords to avoid to injury themselves.

Is the tv show accurate?

Comment: They might use wooden swords at first and then move on to real weapons. Also worth considering: it's easy enough to move slowly at first to avoid injury, even with a real weapon.  By the time you're training at full speed, you should be able to handle the weapon well enough that the risk of actually hurting your sparring partner is minimal.

Answer (score 3):

As someone who Trains HEMA, let me tell you weapons completly made out of wood are ligther and have a different ballance. So training with tem might give you a wrong feeling for the weapon, its weight and even reach. And yes we use also real weapons,blunt ones tough, but real enough. So training with real weapons even if Blunt ones, gives them a better feel and more strength for their weapon.

Comment: Thanks, online I found that there are specific wood swords that are heavier than the real ones actually. I guess the experience may vary. But the point is still that no one uses real sharp swords right? In the show they use the exact same sword you see during the battles.

Comment: Could you define real? A blunt steel sword is real enough i think ,broke my thumb a few weeks ago with one, but you can alway sharpen them, thus making them the same sword.

Comment: For real I mean, sharp, ready to kill. You almost broken the thumb, if it was real you would have said "I almost severed my thumb". At least that's what I mean for "real" in this context. In the show they often show that the same weapon that was being used to train, a moment after is used to kill someone.

Comment: It wasn't almost broken, it was broken. And yes with a sharp sword it would have been severed. If they really show it like this, than they either train with sharp weapons, or have inconsitensi issues in the series.